# How to merge arrays of objects into other objects

Tags: c#, linq

my first question on StackOverflow. I have searched the web but have not found such a specific case. I will try to be as specific as possible.

I have a `Data` array of objects:

```
Data: 
[  
    { ID:"ID1", Name:"Name1", Date:"2015-08-21", TypeA:{ Count:1 }, TypeB:{ Count:2 } },  
    { ID:"ID2", Name:"Name2", Date:"2015-08-21", TypeA:{ Count:3 }, TypeB:{ Count:4 } },  
    { ID:"ID3", Name:"Name3", Date:"2015-08-23", TypeA:{ Count:5 }, TypeB:{ Count:6 } }  
]
```

I am trying to group all these arrays of object into new objects based on the `Type` Property, i.e. if the `TypeX.Count > 0` then add it to the Type main object. Then add them based on the `Date` property, if the dates are the same then merge them under the same date:

```
TypeA:
{  
  Dates:
  [ 
    { Date: "2015-08-21",
      Data: 
      [ 
        { ID: "ID1", Name: "Name1", Count: 1 },
        { ID: "ID2", Name: "Name2", Count: 3 }
      ]
    },
    { Date: "2015-08-23",
      Data: 
      [ 
        { ID: "ID3", Name: "Name1", Count: 5 }
      ]
    }
  ]  
},
TypeB:
{
  Dates:
  [ 
    { Date: "2015-08-21",
      Data: 
      [ 
        { ID: "ID1", Name: "Name1", Count: 2 },
        { ID: "ID2", Name: "Name2", Count: 4 }
      ]
    },
    { Date: "2015-08-23",
      Data: 
      [ 
        { ID: "ID3", Name: "Name3", Count: 6 }
      ]
    }
  ] 
}
```

I have done this using Javascript, but now I need to transfer the whole logic to the server side - C#/linq.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you always have a TypeA and a TypeB, or are they optional. Can you have e.g. a TypeC as well?

Comment: Hi Micke, there is a total of 6 types, basically 2 groups by 3, so the object can have one group of three or the other. Count is the same property for all types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) twice:-

```
var result = Data.GroupBy(x => x.Type)
                 .Select(x => new 
                        {
                             TypeAB = x.Key,
                             Obj = x.GroupBy(z => z.Date)
                                    .Select(z => new 
                                            {
                                                Date = z.Key,
                                                InnerObj = z.Select(i => new 
                                                             {
                                                                 Id = i.Id,
                                                                 Name = i.Name,
                                                                 Count = i.Count
                                                             })
                                            }).ToArray()
                       });
```

First group by `Type`, which will return the `Key` (nothing but TypeA, TypeB etc.) and an IEnumerable (objects within each Type). Further Group this list by `Date` and project the Key as well as other objects. Here I am projecting anonymous type you can select the actual `Type` if you have one.